# Vue.js can't copy array to another array

Tags: arrays, vue.js, copy

I'm trying to copy an array to another array and I'm getting that error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name'
>   of undefined"

My code:

```
props: {
    languages: {
        required: true,
    },
},
data() {
       return {
           translations: [],
       }
},
mounted() {
        this.setTranslations();
},
methods: {
        setTranslations() {
               this.translations = this.languages.slice(0);
        }
},
```

Same result with:

```
this.translations = this.languages
```

and:

```
let temp = this.languages.slice(0); 
this.translations = temp;
```

> EDIT

If I comment that line:

```
// this.translations = this.languages.slice(0);
```

Error disappears.

This also does not work:

```
this.languages.forEach( function (item) {
     this.translations.push(item);
});
```

I'm getting error:

> Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'translations'
>   of undefined"

But this works:

```
let temp = this.languages.slice(0);

temp.forEach( function ( lang ) {
    Vue.set(lang, 'value', {});
    Vue.set(lang.value, 'name', "");
    Vue.set(lang.value, 'metaKeywords', "");
    Vue.set(lang.value, 'metaDescription', "");
});

this.translations = temp;
```

Although that way my languages array became the same as translations array, which is not what I want.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add your html template? Seams it tries to render {{something.name}} and something does not exists.

Comment: It is not from template, because if I comment that line:  // this.translations = this.languages.slice(0); this error is gone.

Comment: @Lunfel Actually you are right, the problem is in template, and it is because it can't find "name". But I don't know why this error appears when I try to copy array. "name" is not there also if I comment that line.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this error comes from template. Template depends on "name" in my translations array. And it cant find it. That's why my last code works. 
I don't know why console does not show error when I comment array copy line. It should show the same error.

Comment: If you use a v-for, the template will not render for an empty array. But if you have a non-empty array with elements that do not have a "name" attribute, it will trigger that error